# Site analytics does not consider Duck Duck Go a search engine

Tags: bug, site-analytics

From the [site analytics traffic page](https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources):

[image]

Shouldn't [Duck Duck Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DuckDuckGo) be listed under "search" instead? According to wikipedia,

> DuckDuckGo is an Internet search engine that ...

Comment: What is the site analytics traffic page supposed to contain? Any traffic but search engines? What is an example of a domain not *duckduck.go* in the figure? *[Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/)*? *[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)*?